# Trying to return ONLY tomorrow's data using Swift and Core Data but it returns both today's and tomorrow's together?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to return ONLY tomorrow's data using Swift and Core Data but it returns both today's and tomorrow's together. Any idea why? Below is the code I am using. Thank you in advance!

```
   let today = NSDate()
   let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        .dateByAddingUnit(
            .Day,
            value: 1,
            toDate: today,
            options: []
    )

    todoTomorrow = CoreDataManager.getData("ToDos", predicate: NSPredicate(format:"dueDate<%@", ((tomorrow))!)) as! [ToDos]
```

Comment: You're asking for todo's with dueDate < tomorrow, which includes today's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your predicate to be `dueDate < %@ AND dueDate > %@` with parameters `tomorrow` and `today` so it checks both the upper and lower allowed range of the dates.

Comment: Thanks Wain! I tried writing it again, but still lost... I am very new at this: my first attempt! Here is what I was using:  CoreDataManager.getData("ToDos", predicate: NSPredicate(format:"dueDate>=%@" AND "dueDate<=%@",((startOfDay), (endOfDay)))) as! [ToDos]. I used startOfDay and endOfDay for tomorrow, but I think I am not using the syntax correctly... can't figure out what exactly is wrong

Comment: startOfDay and endOfDay work fine when I pass them as parameters individually... I think I am not using the multiple parameters correctly then?

Comment: Ohhh, I found what was messing it up... dueDate>=%@" AND "dueDate<=%@" (I had 2 extra " " s in the middle!). And I removed the brackets. Thanks for your help - much appreciated!!!